# Factorial calculate fast

Tags: discrete-mathematics, factorial

I have an exercise that has factorial and as I know

> $10!$

I must do it $10 \cdot 1 + 10 \cdot 2 \ldots$ etc and I don't know how I see this solution.  He just written the results,or calculates with another way,faster way?  I will use a computer to calculate it but i don't know how he fast did it.
\begin{align*}
P(n,r) & = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!}\\
       & = \frac{10!}{(10 - 3)!}\\ 
       & = 10 \times 9 \times 8\\ 
       & = 720
\end{align*}

Comment: Please read this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: you don't see?it doesn't mention it that it says 10 * 9 * 8 .As you can see we have 10! /7! that leads to this (10⋅9⋅8⋅7⋅6⋅5⋅4⋅3⋅2⋅1)/(1*2*3*4*5*6*7 ).How the 10*9*8 stays?

Comment: omg now i understand impossible xaxaxax

Comment: he divide 1 until 7 / 7 down and up remain 8 *9*10 .

Comment: If I understand correctly, your question was how does $\frac{10!}{(10 - 3)!}$ simplify to $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8$?  If so, you could answer your own question.

Comment: How the $10⋅9⋅8$ stays? Because $7⋅6⋅5⋅4⋅3⋅2⋅1$ is present in the numerator and in the denominator and so they cancel out.

Comment: yes i understand it :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $$10!=10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1$$
while:
$$7!=7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1$$
hence it is clear that $$\frac{10!}{7!}=10\cdot9\cdot8=720$$